# Trim / remove a tab ( "\t" ) from a string

Tags: c++, string, tabs

Can anyone suggest a way of stripping tab characters ( "\t"s ) from a string? CString or std::string.

So that "1E10      " for example becomes "1E10".

Comment: Do you mean just from the start or end? Or from anywhere in the string? Should "abc\tdef" be left as is, or be reduced to "abcdef"?

Comment: I should have been more clear on this, I meant from anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[hackingwords' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556277/trim-remove-a-tab-t-from-a-string/556293#556293) gets you halfway there.  But [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) from `<algorithm>` doesn't actually make the string any shorter -- it just returns an iterator saying "the new sequence would end here."  You need to call [`my_string().erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) to do that:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // For std::remove()

my_str.erase(std::remove(my_str.begin(), my_str.end(), '\t'), my_str.end());
```

Comment: std::remove() link is broken. Correct link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: @SebiSebi: Thanks for that, fixed!

Answer (score 20):

If you want to remove all occurences in the string, then you can use the [erase/remove](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove) idiom:

```
#include <algorithm>

s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '\t'), s.end());
```

If you want to remove only the tab at the beginning and end of the string, you could use the [boost string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/string_algo.html):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

boost::trim(s); // removes all leading and trailing white spaces
boost::trim_if(s, boost::is_any_of("\t")); // removes only tabs
```

If using Boost is too much overhead, you can roll your own trim function using `find_first_not_of` and `find_last_not_of` string methods.

```
std::string::size_type begin = s.find_first_not_of("\t");
std::string::size_type end   = s.find_last_not_of("\t");

std::string trimmed = s.substr(begin, end-begin + 1);
```

Comment: std::remove() doesn't make the string any shorter -- it just returns an iterator saying "the new string ends here."  You need to call s.erase() afterwards with that iterator to actually shorten the string.

Comment: You're right, I forgot using the erase/remove idiom. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

The [`remove`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/remove) algorithm shifts all characters not to be deleted to the beginning, overwriting deleted characters but it doesn't modify the container's length (since it works on iterators and doesn't know the underlying container). To achieve this, call [`erase`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/erase):

```
str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\t'), str.end());
```

Comment: I think you have the parameters to erase() mixed up.  You want to erase *from* the iterator returned by remove() to the *end* of str.

Comment: P.S: Actually I don't think remove() shifts the found characters to the end -- I think the end will just contain whatever it contained initially.

Comment: @j_r_h: Not, it really does. Basically, `remove(a, b, v)` is exactly equal to `stable_partition(a, b, p)` with the predicate p = `_1 != value`.

Comment: Are you sure?  According to http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove.html: "The iterators in the range [new_last, last) are all still dereferenceable, but the elements that they point to are unspecified."  Certainly the MinGW and MSVC++8 implementations of remove() != stable_partition().

Comment: Also remove() is an in-place O(n) algorithm, while stable_partition() seems to be "harder" -- at least the SGI implementation of stable_partition() tries to allocate a temporary buffer and use that in O(n) time, otherwise falling back to an O(nlog n) algorithm.

Comment: `j_random_hacker`: Sorry, I can't argue from the Standard, I looked at the GCC source. Furthermore, I readily agree that a general-purpose stable sort may be more difficult to implement, however, at least the GCC `remove` implementation does exactly what I said above.

Comment: (cont) And due to the Standard constraints on runtime (exactly N applications I of the predicate) I fail to see any other workable implementation. But that's strictly speculation, I admit.

Comment: @Konrad: Sorry to go on but I have to clear this up!  I just grovelled through the g++ 4.1.2 sources, and it doesn't perform the equivalent of stable_partition() either. What version do you have? (BTW, I couldn't tell if your 2nd comment was in support of your original statement or against it...)

Comment: @j_r_h: My 2nd comment was in support of the original statement. As for the source: GCC 4.2 `remove` invokes `find` and `remove_copy`. `find` gets the first occurrence and `r_c` shifts all subsequent finds to the end.

Comment: (cont'd) That said, I see now that you are right that they are not identical; `remove` just moves the other elements to the front, it does not move the deleted elements to the back. So yes, you were right all along. But I had to test it first: http://pastie.org/396239 So, thanks for persisting!

Comment: @Konrad: No problem, glad we cleared that up and I wasn't losing my mind after all! :)

Answer (score 3):

Since others already answered how to do this with std::string, here's what you can use for CString:

```
myString.TrimRight( '\t' ); // trims tabs from end of string
myString.Trim( '\t' ); // trims tabs from beginning and end of string
```

if you want to get rid of all tabs, even those inside the string, use

```
myString.Replace( _T("\t"), _T("") );
```

Comment: Which header/library to include for using TrimRight and Trim methods on string? I have done #include <cstring>, but this is not appearing in intellisense.

Comment: @FarazAhmad CString Stefan uses is a class of its own. It's from the afx.h header. You can use it by linking to MS common runtime library in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Scan the string and remove all the found occurences.

Answer (score 2):

HackingWords is nearly there: Use erase in combination with remove.

```
std::string my_string = "this\tis\ta\ttabbed\tstring";
my_string.erase( std::remove( my_string.begin(), my_string.end(), '\t'), my_string.end());
```

Comment: I think you made the same mistake as Konrad Rudolph -- you need to delete *from* the iterator returned by std::remove() to the *end* of the string.

Answer (score 1):

CString replace?

> replace('\t', '')

Comment: Won't work. '' stands for NULL character (at least in VC++). Will cause problems.

Comment: More specifically replace( "\t", "" )

Comment: I didn't test is but I inteded to use '\t' because I think "\t" will look for the text \t instead of the tab character (don't know for sure).

Comment: Nope, replace("\t", "") will work just as needed, but it's not very time-efficient. Escape sequences work the same in character literals and string literals.

Answer (score 0):

First idea would be to use [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove.html)

```
remove(myString.begin(), myString.end(), "\t");
```

Though you might have to use remove_if instead if that comparison doesn't work.

Comment: remove() is half of it -- you also need to wrap that call to remove() with a call to myString.erase(), since remove() doesn't actually shorten the string (it doesn't (and can't) know how).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one trims a string this way:

```
void trim (string& s)  {
    string t = "";
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] == ' ') i++;
    while(s[i] == '\t') i++;
    for(i; i < s.length(); i++)
        t += s[i];

    s = t;
}
```

Comment: Because it won't handle correctly all cases. It'll only skip leading spaces, then leading tabs, and only in this order.