# remove double quotes from a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, double-quotes

I am stripping off double quotes from a string, but I keep getting this error from the following function. What is the problem here?

```
void readCSVCell(stringstream& lineStream, string& s) {
    std::getline(lineStream,s,',');
    s.erase(remove( s.begin(), s.end(), '\"' ), s.end());
}
```

[ERROR]

> c.cpp: In function `void readCSVCell(std::stringstream&, std::string&)`:
>   
> c.cpp:11: error: cannot convert `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >` to `const char*` for argument `1` to `int remove(const char*)`

Comment: Have you checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556277/trim-remove-a-tab-t-from-a-string

Comment: Have you included `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: Adding 'algorithm' header file and prefixing with std namespace fixed the problem.

Answer (score 14):

Don't you want something like:

```
s.erase(remove( s.begin(), s.end(), '\"' ),s.end());
```

As `remove` returns "A forward iterator pointing to the new end of the sequence, which now includes all the elements with a value other than value" rather than removing the values.

It compiles fine for me though (with gcc 4.4), so perhaps you just need to include `<algorithm>` and make sure you are either `using namespace std` or qualify the name.

Comment: It compiles fine for me, so I guess the error is with the namespacing of remove or a conflict with another header file as Space_C0wb0y suggests.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have `stdio.h` included? Then there could be a conflict with [`remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/). This is the reason why you always should prefix `std`-calls with, well, `std::`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::remove` not `remove`

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to remove double quotes from string in C++.

```
stringVariable.erase(
    std::remove(stringVariable.begin(), stringVariable.end(), '\"'), 
    stringVariable.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

`remove` is algorithm, hence you need to do `#include <algorithm>`. Then while using you should use it as `std::remove(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

[remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) requires the `algorithm` header and is from `std` namespace

I do find the [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) very helpful for quickly getting usage examples and what headers are required. It may not have complete information for some things but it helps as a good start if I am not sure about how to use some parts of C Library, stream Library, strings library, STL Containers or STL Algorithms